# Unable to load new filament FlashForge Adventurer 3

Tags: filament, change-filament, flashforge-adventurer-3, flashforge

I have a FlashForge Adventurer 3. I have just finished my sample filament today and tried to replace it with a new spool of filament. This new filament is by Hatchbox, instead of FlashForge. Besides that, the new filament is 1.75 mm PLA filament, like the sample spool. However, when I tried to insert the new filament, it doesn't feed in. I get a loud, thumping sound from the printer, but the filament doesn't get fed through. Does anyone know why this is happening or what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I'd try is making sure the nozzle is hot enough and carefully try to feed the new filament where it will be pushed - sometimes there's melted filament that just isn't hot enough to flow out and the new filament is pushing on it, jamming and making your motor make that sound.  Usually getting it hot to the point where the old filament is practically dripping out before attempting to insert the new filament will work.

If that doesn't work I might let the thing cool, disassemble the nozzle, and remove the jam mechanically (and reassemble it).